# Firebase data gets overwritten ! sought guidance

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I am building an Angular App with Firebase.

My intention is to create an object (say Rooms) at the root with 3 child objects (say Room1, Room2 & Room3) . Also, I am trying to create a logic that would check if the Rooms object is there - it wont create it again.

My code was :

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
ref.child('Rooms').once('value', function (snapshot){
  if(snapshot.numChildren() == 0){
    // Create Room within a loop
    ref.child('Rooms').child(i).set(roomObj);
  }else if(snapshot.numChildren() > 0){
    // do not create
  }
}
```

But when the code runs - it always enters into the `if` block !! And creates the child Rooms.

What is my mistake in the code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the value event will be triggered again with the value you expect.

Your solution is to run the code in a transaction.

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
ref.child('Rooms').transaction(function (data){
  if(!data){
    var rooms = {};
    for (var roomNum=0; roomNum < 3; roomNum++) {
      rooms['room'+roomNum] = { name: 'Room '+roomNum };
    }
    return rooms
  }
}
```

So if the rooms don't exist yet, the above code creates them. If they already exist, the code does nothing (not returning a value, leaves the data unmodified).

Be sure to read the [Firebase documentation for `transaction`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions).